# SQL Sort table place "Do not use" records at bottom

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to sort data in a table. I have records that need to be placed at the bottom of the table. Any record with
"Do not use" in the comment column should be at the bottom. The rest are sorted in alphabetical order by comment and CP_Code columns. How can I send records to the bottom of the list if they don't start with "z"?

SQL SERVER 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from yourtable
order by case when comment = 'Do not use' then 1 else 0 end, comment, cp_code
```

The `case` statement sets up a custom value for your 'do not use' comments, and pushes all these records to the bottom of the pile. Then, within the subsets with values 0 and 1 for the custom sort, alphabetical sorting and sorting by `cp_code` is again applied.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/GLIJ4580)

Comment: That worked great. Now how can I alter the table to reflect this order?